# Can I change the whole computer volume?

Tags: windows, audio, windows-registry, usb-headset

I have the volume of my speakers currently always on 2 because it's too loud if it's higher, so I would like to know if I can change the sound volume somehow so that 10 is 40 or something like that so I can regulate the volume more precisely. I use Win10 x64 and an USB Headset.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

- Right click the speaker icon in the task tray (by the clock).
- Select "Open Volume Mixer"
- Left Click on the USB Headset icon to go to its properties
- Select the "Levels" tab
- You can then adjust the headset volume in its properties and the other applications sounds in the volume mixer

Comment: I have USB speakers, and this was the first thing I tried, but unfortunately it does sync with the control panel, and as such it doesn't work. Using the hardware volume buttons adjust these levels too. They're all synced and connected.